# Android Application end without any crash message

Tags: java, unity-game-engine

I'm writing a plugin for Unity Android, with this plugin, user can select their images from gallery. I created a new activity for "onActivityResult" function calls. When I click button in Unity, the gallery opens correctly, but after selecting, my app close without any messages, and in logCat there is many messages, why my app close and how can i solve it, thanks much.

**resimSec.java**

```cs
package com.alptugrul.background;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;

import com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer;

/**
 * Created by Alpaslan on 27.3.2018.
 */

public class resimSec extends Activity {
    public static void resimSec() {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction("com.alptugrul.background.imgSec");
        UnityPlayer.currentActivity.startActivityForResult(intent, imgSec.GalleryRequest);
        Log.e("alpi","baslioruz.");

    }
}
```

**imgSec.java**

```cs
package com.alptugrul.background;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer;
import com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity;

/**
 * Created by Alpaslan on 27.3.2018.
 */

public class imgSec extends UnityPlayerActivity {
    public static int GalleryRequest = 1;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Intent intent = new Intent();

        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        startActivityForResult(intent, GalleryRequest);

    }

    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
            if(requestCode == GalleryRequest){
                // fetch image uri or do whatever you like here
                // send it to Unity ;)
               // UnityPlayer.UnitySendMessage("xx", "xx", "xx");

            }
        }else{
          //  System.out.print("Result code in router:"+resultCode);
        }

        setResult(resultCode);
        finish();
    }
}
```

**imgSec.cs in Unity**

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class imgSec : MonoBehaviour {
    private static string fullClassName = "com.alptugrul.background.resimSec";
    AndroidJavaClass fotoSecClass;
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        fotoSecClass = new AndroidJavaClass(fullClassName);

    }
    public void fotoSec () {
        fotoSecClass.CallStatic ("resimSec");
    }

    public void setIMG (string imgURL) {
        Texture2D tex;
        tex = new Texture2D(4, 4, TextureFormat.DXT1, false);
        using (WWW www = new WWW(imgURL))
        {
            www.LoadImageIntoTexture(tex);
            GetComponent<Renderer>().material.mainTexture = tex;
        }
    }

}
```

**AND THE LOGCAT MESSAGE**

```html
03-27 14:30:16.505 1301-1306/? D/gralloc_ranchu: gralloc_alloc: Creating ashmem region of size 3686400
03-27 14:30:16.554 1301-1559/? E/BufferQueueProducer: [SurfaceView - com.akgames.kazzan/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity] cancelBuffer: BufferQueue has been abandoned
03-27 14:30:16.579 3474-3490/? D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x92a7d2a0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0x93684bc0)
03-27 14:30:16.585 3474-3555/? D/AudioTrack: Client defaulted notificationFrames to 682 for frameCount 2048
03-27 14:30:16.597 3353-3391/? D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xb1185600: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xb1183470)
03-27 14:30:16.628 1309-1332/? D/AudioFlinger: mixer(0xab683ac0) throttle end: throttle time(10)
03-27 14:30:16.639 1309-1332/? D/AudioFlinger: mixer(0xab683ac0) throttle end: throttle time(10)
03-27 14:30:16.876 3474-3474/? W/Unity: Not running Google VR from an Activity; Ignoring execution request...
03-27 14:30:16.879 3474-3474/? I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 3474 SIG: 9
03-27 14:30:16.923 1576-1929/? I/WindowManager: Destroying surface Surface(name=com.android.documentsui/com.android.documentsui.DocumentsActivity) called by com.android.server.wm.WindowStateAnimator.destroySurface:2016 com.android.server.wm.WindowStateAnimator.destroySurfaceLocked:882 com.android.server.wm.WindowState.removeLocked:1456 com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.removeWindowInnerLocked:2484 com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.removeWindowLocked:2442 com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.removeWindowLocked:2311 com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.removeWindow:2306 com.android.server.wm.Session.remove:202 
03-27 14:30:16.937 1576-1620/? W/InputDispatcher: channel 'a5b3e22 com.akgames.kazzan/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity (server)' ~ Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x9
03-27 14:30:16.938 1576-1620/? E/InputDispatcher: channel 'a5b3e22 com.akgames.kazzan/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
03-27 14:30:16.941 1576-1605/? I/WindowManager: WIN DEATH: Window{a5b3e22 u0 com.akgames.kazzan/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity}
03-27 14:30:16.941 1576-1605/? W/InputDispatcher: Attempted to unregister already unregistered input channel 'a5b3e22 com.akgames.kazzan/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity (server)'
03-27 14:30:16.941 1576-1605/? W/WindowManager: Force-removing child win Window{b6239 u0 SurfaceView - com.akgames.kazzan/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity} from container Window{a5b3e22 u0 com.akgames.kazzan/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity}
03-27 14:30:16.941 1576-1605/? I/WindowManager: Destroying surface Surface(name=SurfaceView - com.akgames.kazzan/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity) called by com.android.server.wm.WindowStateAnimator.destroySurface:2016 com.android.server.wm.WindowStateAnimator.destroySurfaceLocked:882 com.android.server.wm.WindowState.removeLocked:1456 com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.removeWindowInnerLocked:2484 com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.removeWindowInnerLocked:2463 com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.removeWindowLocked:2442 com.android.server.wm.WindowState$DeathRecipient.binderDied:1787 android.os.BinderProxy.sendDeathNotice:688 
03-27 14:30:16.945 1576-1605/? I/WindowManager: Destroying surface Surface(name=com.akgames.kazzan/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity) called by com.android.server.wm.WindowStateAnimator.destroySurface:2016 com.android.server.wm.WindowStateAnimator.destroySurfaceLocked:882 com.android.server.wm.WindowState.removeLocked:1456 com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.removeWindowInnerLocked:2484 com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.removeWindowLocked:2442 com.android.server.wm.WindowState$DeathRecipient.binderDied:1787 android.os.BinderProxy.sendDeathNotice:688 <bottom of call stack> 
03-27 14:30:16.949 1576-1588/? W/WindowManager: Failed looking up window
                                                java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Requested window android.os.BinderProxy@61400b3 does not exist
                                                    at com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.windowForClientLocked(WindowManagerService.java:9107)
                                                    at com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.windowForClientLocked(WindowManagerService.java:9098)
                                                    at com.android.server.wm.WindowState$DeathRecipient.binderDied(WindowState.java:1784)
                                                    at android.os.BinderProxy.sendDeathNotice(Binder.java:688)
03-27 14:30:16.949 1576-1588/? I/WindowManager: WIN DEATH: null
03-27 14:30:16.950 1576-2125/? I/ActivityManager: Process com.akgames.kazzan (pid 3474) has died
03-27 14:30:16.950 1576-2125/? D/ActivityManager: cleanUpApplicationRecord -- 3474
03-27 14:30:16.957 1576-2125/? W/ActivityManager: Force removing ActivityRecord{8ec07d4 u0 com.akgames.kazzan/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity t18}: app died, no saved state
03-27 14:30:17.049 2095-2165/? E/EGL_emulation: tid 2165: eglSurfaceAttrib(1227): error 0x3009 (EGL_BAD_MATCH)
03-27 14:30:17.049 2095-2165/? W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0x93699bc0, error=EGL_BAD_MATCH
03-27 14:30:17.060 2095-2165/? D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xa252cf80: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xad530520)
```

If i remove the `finish()` tag from my function, my app stopped working after this. LogCat messages is below.

```html
03-28 19:37:55.302 1301-1304/? D/gralloc_ranchu: gralloc_alloc: Creating ashmem region of size 3686400
                                                 
                                                 
                                                 [ 03-28 19:37:55.354  4006: 4065 D/         ]
                                                 HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0x84c6c640, tid 4065
                                                 
                                                 
                                                 [ 03-28 19:37:55.354  4006: 4065 W/         ]
                                                 Unrecognized GLES max version string in extensions: ANDROID_EMU_CHECKSUM_HELPER_v1 
03-28 19:37:55.354 1301-1306/? E/BufferQueueProducer: [SurfaceView - com.akgames.kazzan/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity] cancelBuffer: BufferQueue has been abandoned
03-28 19:37:55.385 1577-1988/? W/InputMethodManagerService: Starting input on non-focused client com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@59730ee (uid=10010 pid=3699)
03-28 19:37:55.386 4006-4065/? D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x8ad91000: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0x84f7b610)
03-28 19:37:55.388 4006-4065/? A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x54 in tid 4065 (UnityMain)
                                       
                                       [ 03-28 19:37:55.388  1259: 1259 W/         ]
                                       debuggerd: handling request: pid=4006 uid=10086 gid=10086 tid=4065
03-28 19:37:55.390 3699-3745/? D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x9fc055a0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0x9fc036d0)
03-28 19:37:55.449 4073-4073/? A/DEBUG: *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
03-28 19:37:55.449 4073-4073/? A/DEBUG: Build fingerprint: 'google/sdk_google_phone_x86/generic_x86:7.0/NYC/4409132:userdebug/dev-keys'
03-28 19:37:55.449 4073-4073/? A/DEBUG: Revision: '0'
03-28 19:37:55.449 4073-4073/? A/DEBUG: ABI: 'x86'
03-28 19:37:55.449 4073-4073/? A/DEBUG: pid: 4006, tid: 4065, name: UnityMain  >>> com.akgames.kazzan <<<
03-28 19:37:55.449 4073-4073/? A/DEBUG: signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x54
03-28 19:37:55.449 4073-4073/? A/DEBUG:     eax 00000000  ebx 8ed4fc04  ecx 00000001  edx 00000001
03-28 19:37:55.449 4073-4073/? A/DEBUG:     esi 88cfdf20  edi 00000001
03-28 19:37:55.449 4073-4073/? A/DEBUG:     xcs 00000073  xds 0000007b  xes 0000007b  xfs 0000003b  xss 0000007b
03-28 19:37:55.449 4073-4073/? A/DEBUG:     eip 8eba62e9  ebp 88cfdd98  esp 88cfdd60  flags 00010286
03-28 19:37:55.450 4073-4073/? A/DEBUG: backtrace:
03-28 19:37:55.450 4073-4073/? A/DEBUG:     #00 pc 001cb2e9  /data/app/com.akgames.kazzan-1/lib/x86/libmono.so
03-28 19:37:55.450 4073-4073/? A/DEBUG:     #01 pc 001d0bb0  /data/app/com.akgames.kazzan-1/lib/x86/libmono.so (mono_array_new+130)
03-28 19:37:55.450 4073-4073/? A/DEBUG:     #02 pc 00579a35  /data/app/com.akgames.kazzan-1/lib/x86/libunity.so
03-28 19:37:55.450 4073-4073/? A/DEBUG:     #03 pc 006a47f7  /data/app/com.akgames.kazzan-1/lib/x86/libunity.so
03-28 19:37:55.450 4073-4073/? A/DEBUG:     #04 pc 006a7226  /data/app/com.akgames.kazzan-1/lib/x86/libunity.so
03-28 19:37:55.450 4073-4073/? A/DEBUG:     #05 pc 006b18a2  /data/app/com.akgames.kazzan-1/lib/x86/libunity.so
03-28 19:37:55.450 4073-4073/? A/DEBUG:     #06 pc 001a4738  /data/app/com.akgames.kazzan-1/oat/x86/base.odex (offset 0x180000)
03-28 19:37:55.893 1577-4078/? W/ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity com.akgames.kazzan/com.alptugrul.background.imgSec
03-28 19:37:55.896 1577-1595/? I/BootReceiver: Copying /data/tombstones/tombstone_06 to DropBox (SYSTEM_TOMBSTONE)
                                               
                                               [ 03-28 19:37:55.900  1259: 1259 W/         ]
                                               debuggerd: resuming target 4006
03-28 19:37:55.903 1577-4078/? E/JavaBinder: !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!  (parcel size = 104)
03-28 19:37:55.905 1577-4078/? W/ActivityManager: Exception thrown during pause
                                                  android.os.DeadObjectException: Transaction failed on small parcel; remote process probably died
                                                      at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(Native Method)
                                                      at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Binder.java:615)
                                                      at android.app.ApplicationThreadProxy.schedulePauseActivity(ApplicationThreadNative.java:784)
                                                      at com.android.server.am.ActivityStack.startPausingLocked(ActivityStack.java:1128)
                                                      at com.android.server.am.ActivityStack.finishActivityLocked(ActivityStack.java:3483)
                                                      at com.android.server.am.ActivityStack.finishTopRunningActivityLocked(ActivityStack.java:3319)
                                                      at com.android.server.am.ActivityStackSupervisor.finishTopRunningActivityLocked(ActivityStackSupervisor.java:1842)
                                                      at com.android.server.am.AppErrors.handleAppCrashLocked(AppErrors.java:619)
                                                      at com.android.server.am.AppErrors.makeAppCrashingLocked(AppErrors.java:481)
                                                      at com.android.server.am.AppErrors.crashApplicationInner(AppErrors.java:357)
                                                      at com.android.server.am.AppErrors.crashApplication(AppErrors.java:309)
                                                      at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.handleApplicationCrashInner(ActivityManagerService.java:13313)
                                                      at com.android.server.am.NativeCrashListener$NativeCrashReporter.run(NativeCrashListener.java:86)
03-28 19:37:55.910 1577-4078/? E/JavaBinder: !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!  (parcel size = 56)
03-28 19:37:55.914 1577-4078/? E/JavaBinder: !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!  (parcel size = 56)
03-28 19:37:55.919 1577-4078/? E/JavaBinder: !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!  (parcel size = 112)
03-28 19:37:55.920 1577-4078/? I/ActivityManager: Restarting because process died: ActivityRecord{b998be6 u0 com.akgames.kazzan/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity t21}
03-28 19:37:55.924 1577-4078/? E/JavaBinder: !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!  (parcel size = 2304)
03-28 19:37:55.928 1577-4078/? W/ActivityManager: Exception when starting activity com.akgames.kazzan/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity
                                                  android.os.DeadObjectException: Transaction failed on small parcel; remote process probably died
                                                      at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(Native Method)
                                                      at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Binder.java:615)
                                                      at android.app.ApplicationThreadProxy.scheduleLaunchActivity(ApplicationThreadNative.java:883)
                                                      at com.android.server.am.ActivityStackSupervisor.realStartActivityLocked(ActivityStackSupervisor.java:1296)
                                                      at com.android.server.am.ActivityStackSupervisor.startSpecificActivityLocked(ActivityStackSupervisor.java:1395)
                                                      at com.android.server.am.ActivityStack.resumeTopActivityInnerLocked(ActivityStack.java:2514)
                                                      at com.android.server.am.ActivityStack.resumeTopActivityUncheckedLocked(ActivityStack.java:2106)
                                                      at com.android.server.am.ActivityStackSupervisor.resumeFocusedStackTopActivityLocked(ActivityStackSupervisor.java:1820)
                                                      at com.android.server.am.ActivityStackSupervisor.resumeFocusedStackTopActivityLocked(ActivityStackSupervisor.java:1810)
                                                      at com.android.server.am.ActivityStack.startPausingLocked(ActivityStack.java:1183)
                                                      at com.android.server.am.ActivityStack.finishActivityLocked(ActivityStack.java:3483)
                                                      at com.android.server.am.ActivityStack.finishTopRunningActivityLocked(ActivityStack.java:3319)
                                                      at com.android.server.am.ActivityStackSupervisor.finishTopRunningActivityLocked(ActivityStackSupervisor.java:1842)
                                                      at com.android.server.am.AppErrors.handleAppCrashLocked(AppErrors.java:619)
                                                      at com.android.server.am.AppErrors.makeAppCrashingLocked(AppErrors.java:481)
                                                      at com.android.server.am.AppErrors.crashApplicationInner(AppErrors.java:357)
                                                      at com.android.server.am.AppErrors.crashApplication(AppErrors.java:309)
                                                      at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.handleApplicationCrashInner(ActivityManagerService.java:13313)
                                                      at com.android.server.am.NativeCrashListener$NativeCrashReporter.run(NativeCrashListener.java:86)
03-28 19:37:55.928 1577-4078/? D/ActivityManager: cleanUpApplicationRecord -- 4006
03-28 19:37:55.933 1577-4078/? E/JavaBinder: !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!  (parcel size = 56)
03-28 19:37:55.936 1577-1621/? W/InputDispatcher: channel '6f4da04 com.akgames.kazzan/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity (server)' ~ Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x9
03-28 19:37:55.936 1577-1621/? E/InputDispatcher: channel '6f4da04 com.akgames.kazzan/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
03-28 19:37:55.936 1577-1621/? W/InputDispatcher: channel '5b9ff0b com.akgames.kazzan/com.alptugrul.background.imgSec (server)' ~ Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x9
03-28 19:37:55.936 1577-1621/? E/InputDispatcher: channel '5b9ff0b com.akgames.kazzan/com.alptugrul.background.imgSec (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
03-28 19:37:55.937 1308-1308/? I/Zygote: Process 4006 exited due to signal (11)
03-28 19:37:55.939 1577-4078/? E/JavaBinder: !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!  (parcel size = 56)
03-28 19:37:55.950 1577-1844/? I/WindowManager: WIN DEATH: Window{99c71d7 u0 SurfaceView - com.akgames.kazzan/com.alptugrul.background.imgSec}
03-28 19:37:55.950 1577-1844/? I/WindowManager: Destroying surface Surface(name=SurfaceView - com.akgames.kazzan/com.alptugrul.background.imgSec) called by com.android.server.wm.WindowStateAnimator.destroySurface:2016 com.android.server.wm.WindowStateAnimator.destroySurfaceLocked:882 com.android.server.wm.WindowState.removeLocked:1456 com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.removeWindowInnerLocked:2484 com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.removeWindowLocked:2442 com.android.server.wm.WindowState$DeathRecipient.binderDied:1787 android.os.BinderProxy.sendDeathNotice:688 <bottom of call stack> 
03-28 19:37:55.956 1577-3454/? I/WindowManager: WIN DEATH: Window{6f4da04 u0 com.akgames.kazzan/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity}
03-28 19:37:55.956 1577-3454/? W/InputDispatcher: Attempted to unregister already unregistered input channel '6f4da04 com.akgames.kazzan/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity (server)'
03-28 19:37:55.956 1577-3454/? W/WindowManager: Force-removing child win Window{9901dad u0 SurfaceView - com.akgames.kazzan/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity} from container Window{6f4da04 u0 com.akgames.kazzan/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity}
03-28 19:37:55.959 4080-4080/? W/art: Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86
03-28 19:37:55.959 1577-3453/? W/WindowManager: Failed looking up window
                                                java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Requested window android.os.BinderProxy@3c63bed does not exist
                                                    at com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.windowForClientLocked(WindowManagerService.java:9107)
                                                    at com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.windowForClientLocked(WindowManagerService.java:9098)
                                                    at com.android.server.wm.WindowState$DeathRecipient.binderDied(WindowState.java:1784)
                                                    at android.os.BinderProxy.sendDeathNotice(Binder.java:688)
03-28 19:37:55.959 1577-3453/? I/WindowManager: WIN DEATH: null
03-28 19:37:55.960 1577-1606/? I/WindowManager: WIN DEATH: Window{5b9ff0b u0 com.akgames.kazzan/com.alptugrul.background.imgSec}
03-28 19:37:55.960 1577-1606/? W/InputDispatcher: Attempted to unregister already unregistered input channel '5b9ff0b com.akgames.kazzan/com.alptugrul.background.imgSec (server)'
03-28 19:37:55.960 1577-1606/? I/WindowManager: Destroying surface Surface(name=com.akgames.kazzan/com.alptugrul.background.imgSec) called by com.android.server.wm.WindowStateAnimator.destroySurface:2016 com.android.server.wm.WindowStateAnimator.destroySurfaceLocked:882 com.android.server.wm.WindowState.removeLocked:1456 com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.removeWindowInnerLocked:2484 com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.removeWindowLocked:2442 com.android.server.wm.WindowState$DeathRecipient.binderDied:1787 android.os.BinderProxy.sendDeathNotice:688 <bottom of call stack> 
03-28 19:37:55.962 1577-4078/? I/ActivityManager: Start proc 4080:com.akgames.kazzan/u0a86 for activity com.akgames.kazzan/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity
03-28 19:37:55.980 4080-4087/? E/art: Failed sending reply to debugger: Broken pipe
03-28 19:37:55.980 4080-4087/? I/art: Debugger is no longer active
03-28 19:37:55.980 4080-4087/? I/art: Starting a blocking GC Instrumentation
03-28 19:37:55.984 1577-1598/? I/WindowManager: Destroying surface Surface(name=Starting com.akgames.kazzan) called by com.android.server.wm.WindowStateAnimator.destroySurface:2016 com.android.server.wm.WindowStateAnimator.destroySurfaceLocked:882 com.android.server.wm.WindowState.removeLocked:1456 com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.removeWindowInnerLocked:2484 com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.removeWindowLocked:2442 com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.removeWindowLocked:2311 com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.removeWindow:2306 com.android.server.wm.Session.remove:202 
03-28 19:37:56.011 1577-3058/? I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
03-28 19:37:56.011 1577-3058/? D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 1
03-28 19:37:56.024 1577-3058/? D/EGL_emulation: eglCreateContext: 0x9bdd1820: maj 2 min 0 rcv 2
03-28 19:37:56.039 1577-3058/? D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x9bdd1820: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0x86a033e0)
03-28 19:37:56.048 1577-3058/? E/EGL_emulation: tid 3058: eglSurfaceAttrib(1227): error 0x3009 (EGL_BAD_MATCH)
03-28 19:37:56.048 1577-3058/? W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0x8a639540, error=EGL_BAD_MATCH
03-28 19:37:56.054 1577-3058/? D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x9bdd1820: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0x86a033e0)
03-28 19:37:56.105 1301-3146/? D/gralloc_ranchu: gralloc_alloc: Creating ashmem region of size 3686400
                                                 
                                                 
                                                 [ 03-28 19:37:56.121  4080: 4080 D/         ]
                                                 HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0x9e435740, tid 4080
                                                 
                                                 
                                                 [ 03-28 19:37:56.123  4080: 4080 W/         ]
                                                 Unrecognized GLES max version string in extensions: ANDROID_EMU_CHECKSUM_HELPER_v1 
                                                 
                                                 [ 03-28 19:37:56.124  4080: 4080 W/         ]
                                                 Process pipe failed
03-28 19:37:56.227 1577-1598/? I/ActivityManager: Displayed com.akgames.kazzan/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity: +306ms
03-28 19:37:56.245 1577-3455/? I/WindowManager: Destroying surface Surface(name=com.android.documentsui/com.android.documentsui.DocumentsActivity) called by com.android.server.wm.WindowStateAnimator.destroySurface:2016 com.android.server.wm.WindowStateAnimator.destroySurfaceLocked:882 com.android.server.wm.WindowState.removeLocked:1456 com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.removeWindowInnerLocked:2484 com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.removeWindowLocked:2442 com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.removeWindowLocked:2311 com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.removeWindow:2306 com.android.server.wm.Session.remove:202
```

Comment: I don't know well but this message is suspicious." Not running Google VR from an Activity; Ignoring execution request..."

Comment: If you look at the dump, it's because UnityPlayerActivity is trying to be unregistered twice.  Then you look and say...ARE THOSE REALLY THE TWO NAMES OF YOUR CLASSES?

Comment: If i remove the finish() from function, my app crashes. I added crash message to my topic, please look. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your app closes because you call `finish()` in your `onActivityResult` method.
Removing `finish()` will fix it.

Comment: If i remove the finish() from function, my app crashes. I added crash message to my topic, please look. Thanks.